# Does drawing bitmap on canvas with matrix transformation, effects bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a Bitmap object that I want to draw on canvas with some Matrix transformation. I'm using

```
canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, myMatrix, null);
```

Does such drawing effects object myBitmap? In other words, drawing after that (transformed drawing) myBitmap, **without** myMatrix, will it be drawn without any transformation? or will it have that former transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing on the bitmap will only occur by giving the bitmap to the CTOR of the canvas .

[drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) won't change the bitmap given in the parameters.